# How to split a string by one delimiter but having a particular format as described below

Tags: javascript

I have a string as:

```
const str = 'My [Link format](https://google.com) demo'
```

I want the word array to be like:

```
['My', '[Link format](https://google.com)', 'demo']
```

What to do in javascript?

I was trying using split() and str.match(). Nothing worked yet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i guess something using regex match and trimming whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple split on a space as a delimiter, but we us a negative lookahead to check for the combination of open and closed square brackets `[]` and round brackets `()`

```
const str = 'My [Link format](https://google.com) demo'
console.log(str.split(/\s+(?![^\[]*\])(?![^\(]*\))/));
```

- We also allow for spaces in the URL portion, even though it has a low chance of having spaces, it could still happen

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/m4q6e9x7/

```
["My", "[Link format](https://google.com)", "demo"]
```

In the fiddle I've tried to show to two separate negative lookaheads for the combination of the types of brackets: *(I've put a space in the round brackets to prove the concept)*

```
const str = 'My [Link format](http s://google.com) demo'
```

ignore space between `[]`

```
console.log(str.split(/\s+(?![^\[]*\])/));
["My", "[Link format](http", "s://google.com)", "demo"]
```

ignore space between `()`

```
console.log(str.split(/\s+(?![^\(]*\))/));
["My", "[Link", "format](http s://google.com)", "demo"]
```

So we can easily combine the two criteria because we need both of them to *not* match.

---

Because `[]` and `()` need to be escaped, it might be easier to see the regex if we modify and test for spaces between braces `{}`

```
const str = 'My {Link format}(https://google.com) demo'
console.log(str.split(/\s+(?![^{]*})/));
["My", "{Link format}(https://google.com)", "demo"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions assume, that the string has correct form (meaning basically no space between ']' and '(', no ']' characters inside [...] and similar intuitions. You didn't really provide information about what the input string can be other than your concrete example – so solutions work well in this and very similar cases. Second is very easily modified as needed, first is easily extended to check if the string is in fact not correct.

### Solution using Regular Expressions

Below code finds everything before first '[', everything in '[...](...)' pattern (note: first ... must not contain ']', and second – ')', but I assume this would make for an incorrect input in the first place), and everything after that.
So

```
    let regex = /(.*)(\[.*\]\(.*\))(.*)/
    let res = str.match(regex).splice(1,3)
```

gives `res` as

```
['My ', '[Link format](https://google.com)', ' demo']
```

From there, you can trim every entry in this array (`'My ' => 'My'`) for example using a [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function like so:

```
    res.map((val) => val.trim());
```

Look [here](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#parentheses-contents-in-the-match) for explanation of what the array obtained from .match() method represents, but generally except index 0 it contains capture groups, meaning the parts of string corresponding to parts of regex surrounded by parentheses.
If you are not familiar with Regular Expressions (regexes) in JS, or at all, you will find many online resources about the topic easily. After grasping the basics, [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a nice tool to experiment with regexes and explore their  capabilities. When using it, you should probably choose EcmaSCRIPT/JS flavor from the menu on the left.

### Equivalent solution without regex

Equivalent solution is to find where is the first '[' manually, as well as where the '[...](...)' pattern ends. Than splice the parts (before '[', pattern, and after pattern) from the string, and probably trim them. So just loop over characters of the string in search of '[' and than ']', '(', ')'. Note that in this case you can easily and granularily decide what to do if the string has unexpected/incorrect form.

TODO: I will probably sketch some code when I have time for it

Answer (score 0):

Regex is your friend!

```
const regexMdLinks = /!?\[([^\]]*)\]\(([^\)]+)\)/gm

// Example md file contents
const str = `My [Link format](https://google.com) demo My [Link format2](https://google.com/2) demo2`

let regex_splitted = str.split(regexMdLinks);
let arr = [];
//1. Item will be the text (or empty text)
//2. Item is the link text
//3. Item is the url
for(let i = 0; i < regex_splitted.length; i++){
  if(i % 3 == 0){ //Split normal text
    arr.push(...regex_splitted[i].split(" ").filter(i => i));
  } else if(i % 3 == 1){//Add brackets around link text
    arr.push("["+regex_splitted[i]+"]");
  } else {
    arr.push("("+regex_splitted[i]+")");
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```